# I am not able to send emails with company's domain email address in cake php 2

Tags: email, cakephp-2.3

Following is the code I have used to send email:-  this is my email.php file

```
class EmailConfig {
public $default = array(
'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'timeout' => 30,
'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
'password' => 'secret',
'transport' => 'Smtp'
);

  public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('admin@example.com' => 'Project Name'),
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    'tls' => true
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
 );
}

function i have created in App controller:-

function sendEmail($email, $subject, $body){
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
    $send=$Email->from(array('test@gmail.com'=>'testing Apps'))
        ->to($email)
        ->subject($subject)
                    ->emailFormat('html')
            ->send($body);
 if($send){
    return "sent";
 }else {
    return "error";
 }
}
```

while registration I am able to send maail on gmail,ymail email ids but when i register through my company domain email than it through error

CORE/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php line 51 → MailTransport->_mail(string, string, string, string, null)
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1122 → MailTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Controller/AppController.php line 66 → CakeEmail->send(string)
APP/Controller/UsersController.php line 254 → AppController->sendEmail(string, string, string)
[internal function] → UsersController->register()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(UsersController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 185 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 160 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UsersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

Comment: This is error code. Can you provide error text?

Comment: It might be possible that Google does not allow to send mails with different sender domains than the google domains to prevent spam usage. Have you tried to use the Smtp values of your company's web service and so really send it through your company's domain instead of Google?